# ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Tags: oracle, odbc, connectivity

I'm trying to connect to my RAC database using odbc drivers. While trying I get

> `ORA-28040`: No matching authentication protocol

I have added this in both client and the server:

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8
```

I have also tried by replacing the above mentioned deprecated parameter with the server and client. I still get the same error.

More details:

- Database version 12c
- Client version 12c

Answer (score 2):

This may be Oracle client/server version compatibility issue.

> From [java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol](http://24x7dba.blogspot.com/2017/07/javasqlsqlexception-ora-28040-no.html)
>
> > This happens because you are using a non compatible version of JDBC driver.
> >
> > To resolve this issue, make sure that you are using the latest version of Oracle JDBC driver, if not use JDBC 12c or higher versions.
>
> [image: Compatibility Matrix]

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Answer originally left as a comment by the question author:*</sub>

It worked after adding the new 12c parameters instead of using the deprecated parameters in `sqlnet.ora`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. The problem was that I was trying to connect using SQL Developer 11g but my database was Oracle 12c. The issue disappeared by using the right Oracle SQL Developer version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to resurrect an old web app and make it connect to a newer database, double-check your `build.xml` has the proper class path or if there isn't a `.classpath` lurking about with

```
<classpathentry path="some/path/WEB-INF/maybe-lib/ojdbc14.jar"/>
```

instead of `ojdbc6.jar` or `ojdbc7.jar`, which are actually more recent and the ones you'll want to use.